# Quais configurações são necessárias para fazer o spring boot gerar tabelas automaticamente?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Atualmente estou tentando configurar minha aplicação com spring-boot para gerar tabelas automaticamente mas ainda não sei como, alguem pode ajudar?

Comment: Acho que sua pergunta deveria ser mais específica. Recomendo esse tutorial aqui: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

Você deve criar o arquivo `application.properties` e configurar seu banco de dados nele. Exemplo:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost/meu-banco
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Quando o parâmetro `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` está configurado como `update`, ao iniciar a aplicação, o Hibernate irá verificar se as tabelas já foram criadas, se ainda não tiverem sido criadas, irá criá-las automaticamente.

Outro detalhe, é que para criar as tabelas, suas entidades devem ser anotadas com `@Entity`